# Contacts code separated from 4.0.3

Tags: android

I have separated contacts from 4.0.3 and is compiled successfully. When I try to install this, it throws the following error:

```
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601): Writing exception to parcel
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601): java.lang.SecurityException: The caller must have permissions com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL AND com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_WRITE_ALL_VOICEMAIL
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601):   at com.android.providers.contacts.VoicemailPermissions.checkCallerHasFullAccess(VoicemailPermissions.java:64)
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601):   at com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider.checkVoicemailPermissionAndAddRestriction(CallLogProvider.java:289)
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601):   at com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider.query(CallLogProvider.java:132)
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:178)
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601):   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
01-27 05:31:21.865: E/DatabaseUtils(601):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-27 05:31:21.996: E/DatabaseUtils(601): Writing exception to parcel
01-27 05:31:21.996: E/DatabaseUtils(601): java.lang.SecurityException: The caller must have permissions com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL AND com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_WRITE_ALL_VOICEMAIL
```

Though the below lines are in contact manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_WRITE_ALL_VOICEMAIL" />
```

Comment: though I below lines are in contact manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_WRITE_ALL_VOICEMAIL" />

Answer (score 1):

There's this little bit of information that is not included in the Google Documentation for the VoicemailContract, which would explain your problem:

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html (scroll down to "Voicemail Provider")

> **Voicemail Provider**
>
> The new Voicemail Provider allows applications to add voicemails to
>   the device, in order to present all the user's voicemails in a single
>   visual presentation. For instance, it’s possible that a user has
>   multiple voicemail sources, such as one from the phone’s service
>   provider and others from VoIP or other alternative voice services.
>   These apps can use the Voicemail Provider APIs to add their voicemails
>   to the device. The built-in Phone application then presents all
>   voicemails to the user in a unified presentation. Although the
>   system’s Phone application is the only application that can read all
>   the voicemails, each application that provides voicemails can read
>   those that it has added to the system (but cannot read voicemails from
>   other services).
>
> Because the APIs currently do not allow third-party apps to read all
>   the voicemails from the system, the only third-party apps that should
>   use the voicemail APIs are those that have voicemail to deliver to the
>   user.
>
> The VoicemailContract class defines the content provider for the
>   Voicemail Provder. The subclasses VoicemailContract.Voicemails and
>   VoicemailContract.Status provide tables in which apps can insert
>   voicemail data for storage on the device. For an example of a
>   voicemail provider app, see the Voicemail Provider Demo.

So...basically, even though they have this new API (which is cool and useful), you would only have access to a Voicemail that your app inserted into the DB. You don't have access to any other voicemail that your device has.

I still am not sure if the Broadcast Intent should be fired for all apps on the device or only the system app(s), but since I am not receiving this broadcast, I can only assume that it's for the system app(s) only.

Essentially, my guess is that your compiled version of the Contacts app tries to access all voicemail in its code, resulting in your exception. It would normally be able to do this without a problem as it is a system app with a system signature, but when you install it yourself that no longer applies.

Comment: Hi Raghav, I have seen that you separated Launcher2 from 4.0.3. Have you ever separate Contacts app?.

Comment: No, sorry. I've only separated the Email and Launcher2 apps.

Comment: @Raghav can i  get voicemail count atleast?i.e number of unread voicemail's count?